# Swift Get First Date of Month not working

Tags: swift

I am trying to get the month and year of a date so I can generate month sections in a table view. My plan is to create a dictionary of dates that contains the unique months per year (January 2022:[], January 2023:[]) as the keys, and then each item containing an array of all the dates

When I run the below code, it gets the first date of the month for some dates, but it seems to get the last date of the month for others and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

### Code

```
let dateList = ["2023-01-26 02:30:53 +0000",
                "2022-12-28 09:42:27 +0000",
                "2022-11-09 05:48:42 +0000",
                "2022-09-30 09:08:03 +0000",
                "2022-08-31 10:22:31 +0000",
                "2022-07-29 04:15:02 +0000",
                "2022-06-20 12:57:35 +0000",
                "2022-05-12 15:36:37 +0000",
                "2022-04-18 03:14:29 +0000",
                "2022-03-10 02:40:42 +0000",
                "2022-02-07 18:03:15 +0000",
                "2022-01-18 15:18:24 +0000"]

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

for dates in dateList {
    let currentDate = dateFormatter.date(from:dates)!
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(
        [.month, .year],
        from: currentDate
    )

    let monthName = Calendar.current.monthSymbols[components.month!-1]
    let year = components.year!
    
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
    let month = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
    
    print("\(currentDate) |||||", "\(month!) |||||", "\(components.month!-1) |||||", "\(year) \(monthName)")
}
```

### Output

```
      Original Date                First Date of Month                    monthName
2023-01-26 02:30:53 +0000 ||||| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 0 ||||| 2023 January
2022-12-28 09:42:27 +0000 ||||| 2022-12-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 11 ||||| 2022 December
2022-11-09 05:48:42 +0000 ||||| 2022-11-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 10 ||||| 2022 November
2022-09-30 09:08:03 +0000 ||||| 2022-08-31 23:00:00 +0000 ||||| 8 ||||| 2022 September
2022-08-31 10:22:31 +0000 ||||| 2022-07-31 23:00:00 +0000 ||||| 7 ||||| 2022 August
2022-07-29 04:15:02 +0000 ||||| 2022-06-30 23:00:00 +0000 ||||| 6 ||||| 2022 July
2022-06-20 12:57:35 +0000 ||||| 2022-05-31 23:00:00 +0000 ||||| 5 ||||| 2022 June
2022-05-12 15:36:37 +0000 ||||| 2022-04-30 23:00:00 +0000 ||||| 4 ||||| 2022 May
2022-04-18 03:14:29 +0000 ||||| 2022-03-31 23:00:00 +0000 ||||| 3 ||||| 2022 April
2022-03-10 02:40:42 +0000 ||||| 2022-03-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2 ||||| 2022 March
2022-02-07 18:03:15 +0000 ||||| 2022-02-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 1 ||||| 2022 February
2022-01-18 15:18:24 +0000 ||||| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 0 ||||| 2022 January
```

### Expected Output

```
2023-01-26 02:30:53 +0000 ||||| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 0 ||||| 2023 January
2022-12-28 09:42:27 +0000 ||||| 2022-12-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 11 ||||| 2022 December
2022-11-09 05:48:42 +0000 ||||| 2022-11-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 10 ||||| 2022 November
2022-09-30 09:08:03 +0000 ||||| 2022-09-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 8 ||||| 2022 September
2022-08-31 10:22:31 +0000 ||||| 2022-08-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 7 ||||| 2022 August
2022-07-29 04:15:02 +0000 ||||| 2022-07-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 6 ||||| 2022 July
2022-06-20 12:57:35 +0000 ||||| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 5 ||||| 2022 June
2022-05-12 15:36:37 +0000 ||||| 2022-05-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 4 ||||| 2022 May
2022-04-18 03:14:29 +0000 ||||| 2022-04-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 3 ||||| 2022 April
2022-03-10 02:40:42 +0000 ||||| 2022-03-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2 ||||| 2022 March
2022-02-07 18:03:15 +0000 ||||| 2022-02-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 1 ||||| 2022 February
2022-01-18 15:18:24 +0000 ||||| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 0 ||||| 2022 January
```

As you can see, September - April seem to have the wrong date created by the `let month = Calendar.current.date(from: components)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: It’s a combination of the debug output of printing a Date instance being in GMT and your local timezone being on Daylight Saving Time part of the year. Your code is actually working just fine. It’s just a matter of misunderstanding the meaning of the output.

Comment: I'm not sure, because the dictionary keys also show the incorrect dates:

[2022-01-01 00:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-08-31 23:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-05-31 23:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-03-01 00:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-02-01 00:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-11-01 00:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-06-30 23:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-07-31 23:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-12-01 00:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-04-30 23:00:00 +0000: [], 
2023-01-01 00:00:00 +0000: [], 
2022-03-31 23:00:00 +0000: []]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine.

The *odd behaviour* occurs because `print` displays `Date` instances **always** in UTC.

Either create a string with the `DateFormatter` which does consider the current locale (recommended) or to fix the output of this code just replace the `print` line with

```
print("\(currentDate) |||||", "\(month!.description(with: .current)) |||||", "\(components.month!-1) |||||", "\(year) \(monthName)")
```

`.description(with: .current)` displays the `Date` in the current locale.

Answer (score -1):

It's the localisation that's wrong. The date itself is correct, but the print outputs the date using your current timezone. Make sure to use the same date formatter in your print to get the same print result:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

let dateList = ["2023-01-26 02:30:53 +0000",
                "2022-12-28 09:42:27 +0000",
                "2022-11-09 05:48:42 +0000",
                "2022-09-30 09:08:03 +0000",
                "2022-08-31 10:22:31 +0000",
                "2022-07-29 04:15:02 +0000",
                "2022-06-20 12:57:35 +0000",
                "2022-05-12 15:36:37 +0000",
                "2022-04-18 03:14:29 +0000",
                "2022-03-10 02:40:42 +0000",
                "2022-02-07 18:03:15 +0000",
                "2022-01-18 15:18:24 +0000"]

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

for dateString in dateList {
    let currentDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .year], from: currentDate)

    let monthName = Calendar.current.monthSymbols[components.month!-1]
    let year = components.year!

    let monthDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)

    print("\(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)) |||||", "\(dateFormatter.string(from: monthDate!)) |||||", "\(components.month!-1) |||||", "\(year) \(monthName)")
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is incorrect. The OP’s print statements are printing dates in UTC time because that’s the default output of printing a Date. Changing the locale of the DateFormatter will not change the output at all, and certainly not the timezone. And a DateFormatter’s locale already defaults to the user’s locale.

Comment: Using a DateFormatter will fix the issue as it uses the timezone that comes from the locale. I get the expected result using the code above.

Comment: @Daniel OP wants Date objects as output and not strings to start with and as have been pointed out by HangarRash the dates OP gets are correct and it’s only the output when printing them that is confusing.

Comment: I did write "The date itself is correct...", so he already had what he wanted. Plus I showed a non confusing way to print a date. Clearly he wants to visually compare the dates with the print. Well, whatever...

Comment: So when I set the Calendar .timeZone to .gmt, it works as expected. When it is set to .current, it doesn't.

What am I missing regarding .current? It looks like for some dates, it switches. Is this because those dates fall within the daylight savings period and Swift automatically applies it?

If so, that is definitely counter productive to what I want.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured out why I was getting the odd behaviour.

Using `Calendar.current.date(from: components)` to create a date by only using the month and year creates a date that is the first hour of the month. I think what happens is that daylight savings time is then applied to that new date object, subtracting one hour for the dates that fall with the daylight savings period (March - October).

That explains why only April - September dates were only affected.

Changing the month constant to `dateFormatter.date(from: "\(year)-\(components.month!)-01 00:00:00 +0000")` gets the expected result that I am after, as you can see by the updated code below.

### Code

```
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

let dateList = ["2023-01-26 02:30:53 +0000",
                "2022-12-28 09:42:27 +0000",
                "2022-11-09 05:48:42 +0000",
                "2022-09-30 09:08:03 +0000",
                "2022-08-31 10:22:31 +0000",
                "2022-07-29 04:15:02 +0000",
                "2022-06-20 12:57:35 +0000",
                "2022-05-12 15:36:37 +0000",
                "2022-04-18 03:14:29 +0000",
                "2022-03-10 02:40:42 +0000",
                "2022-02-07 18:03:15 +0000",
                "2022-01-18 15:18:24 +0000",
                "2022-09-30 09:08:03 +0000",
                "2022-08-31 10:22:31 +0000",
                "2022-07-29 04:15:02 +0000",
                "2022-06-20 12:57:35 +0000",
                "2022-05-12 15:36:37 +0000",
                "2022-04-18 03:14:29 +0000",
                "2023-01-26 02:30:53 +0000"]

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

for dates in dateList {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    let currentDate = dateFormatter.date(from:dates)!
    var components = calendar.dateComponents(
        [.day, .month, .year],
        from: currentDate
    )
    
    let monthName = calendar.monthSymbols[components.month!-1]
    let year = components.year!
    let month = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(year)-\(components.month!)-01 00:00:00 +0000")
    
    print("\(currentDate) |||||", "\(month!) |||||", "\(year) \(monthName)")
}
```

### Output

```
2023-01-26 02:30:53 +0000 ||||| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2023-1-1 ||||| 2023 January
2022-12-28 09:42:27 +0000 ||||| 2022-12-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-12-1 ||||| 2022 December
2022-11-09 05:48:42 +0000 ||||| 2022-11-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-11-1 ||||| 2022 November
2022-09-30 09:08:03 +0000 ||||| 2022-09-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-9-1 ||||| 2022 September
2022-08-31 10:22:31 +0000 ||||| 2022-08-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-8-1 ||||| 2022 August
2022-07-29 04:15:02 +0000 ||||| 2022-07-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-7-1 ||||| 2022 July
2022-06-20 12:57:35 +0000 ||||| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-6-1 ||||| 2022 June
2022-05-12 15:36:37 +0000 ||||| 2022-05-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-5-1 ||||| 2022 May
2022-04-18 03:14:29 +0000 ||||| 2022-04-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-4-1 ||||| 2022 April
2022-03-10 02:40:42 +0000 ||||| 2022-03-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-3-1 ||||| 2022 March
2022-02-07 18:03:15 +0000 ||||| 2022-02-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-2-1 ||||| 2022 February
2022-01-18 15:18:24 +0000 ||||| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-1-1 ||||| 2022 January
2022-09-30 09:08:03 +0000 ||||| 2022-09-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-9-1 ||||| 2022 September
2022-08-31 10:22:31 +0000 ||||| 2022-08-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-8-1 ||||| 2022 August
2022-07-29 04:15:02 +0000 ||||| 2022-07-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-7-1 ||||| 2022 July
2022-06-20 12:57:35 +0000 ||||| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-6-1 ||||| 2022 June
2022-05-12 15:36:37 +0000 ||||| 2022-05-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-5-1 ||||| 2022 May
2022-04-18 03:14:29 +0000 ||||| 2022-04-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2022-4-1 ||||| 2022 April
2023-01-26 02:30:53 +0000 ||||| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 ||||| 2023-1-1 ||||| 2023 January
```

Thank you everyone for responding, I hope this helps someone else.